# Rails 3.2.11 rendering unicode in erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

I'm trying to render unicode in my erb template, e.g:

My seed:

```
Currency.create!(currency: 'USD', rate: 1.2805, title: 'U.S. Dollars', code: '\u0024', active: 1)
```

Controller:

```
@currencies = []
Currency.where(:active => TRUE).each do |node|
   c = node.rate * 25
   c = number_to_currency(c, :precision => 2, :unit => node.code)
   @currencies.push(:currency => node.currency, :price => c)
end
```

Template.erb:

```
<select>
    <% @currencies.each do |node| %>
        <option>
            <%= node[:currency] %> - <%= node[:price] %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

I expect this:

```
<option>USD - $32.01</option>
```

But I get the raw unicode output:

```
<option>USD - \u002432.01</option>
```

I've tried:

Adding a utf8 encoding meta attribute. Adding: <%# encoding: utf-8 %> to my template. And using .html_safe on the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using single quotes in your seed. It should be double quotes:

```
"\u0024" # => "$"
'\u0024' # => "\\u0024"
```